BTT Pi fails to list USB connection with `ls /dev/serial/by-id/*` (or /by-path/*); how to connect to the controller board MCU?
I'm in the process of converting my main CoreXY printer to Klipper firmware. I acquired a BTT (BigTreeTech) Pi v1.2 and a BTT Octopus Pro v1.1. The latter is using the STM32H723ZET6 microprocessor.
I downloaded the BTT Pi image (as it is not compatible with Raspbian) using their official image CB1_Debian11_Klipper_kernel5.16_20240319.img.xz found here.

Note that the WiFi of the BTT Pi only supports 2.4 GHz!

I proceeded by creating a firmware.bin file (called/renamed from the klipper.bin in the ~/klipper/out/ directory) after compiling the firmware using the following options for my controller board:
Micro-controller Architecture (STMicroelectronics STM32)  --->
Processor model (STM32H723)  --->
Bootloader offset (128KiB bootloader)  --->
Clock Reference (25 MHz crystal)  --->
Communication interface (USB to CAN bus bridge (USB on PA11/PA12))  --->
CAN bus interface (CAN bus (on PD0/PD1))  --->
USB ids  --->
(1000000) CAN bus speed

From the configuration:

I copied the firmware.bin onto an SD card and booted the Octopus board.
To give your BTT Pi access to the MCU of the controller board, the Klipper documentation, more precisely: "Where's my serial port?" can be consulted to find the address of the USB connection using ls /dev/serial/by-id/*. However this doesn't work!
Looking up the problems hints to using ls /dev/serial/by-path/* instead, but this also fails!
This is because the /serial/ directory doesn't exist!

How do I connect the BTT Pi to the Octopus Pro MCU over the serial connection?

No idea WRT to Klipper and special RPi OS's. But since there are no responses over 2 days I can suggest general Linux approaches. The method described above might work. But instead of looking at /dev/serial..., just look at /dev w/ & w/oi the BTT USB serial port plugged into the RPi and note any new devices. Unless there are unusual UDEV rules, there should be a new device appearing in the /dev directory. Probably w/a name like "ttyUSB0" or "ttyUSB1".

Yes it should be one of those. I ditched the BTT Pi and use a RPi 4 now, works as a charm. As a side project I'm now in the process of configuring Armbian and use KIAUH to install the rest on the BTT Pi, note that the latter doesn't run recent versions of Armbian, an older version does seem to boot.

I ended up not using the supplied CB1 image from BTT instead a vanilla/standard Armbian distribution was installed. This installation did not have the problems listed on the question.
Running Klipper now on my CoreXY HyperCube Evolution.
